# Showing series in Banach space is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Suppoes $(X,\|\cdot \|)$ is a Banach space and $g \geq 0$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g(i) < \infty$. Suppose $f,f_n: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise, meaning that $\| f_n(i)-f(i)\| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Also assume that $\|f_n(i)\| \leq g(i)$ for all $n,i \geq 1$.

 I have proved that $\sum_{i\geq 1} f_n(i)$ converges for fixed $n$. I did this by showing that the sequence of partial sums $s_k=\sum_{i=1}^k f_n(i)$ is Cauchy (and so converges since $X$ is Banach):

 Since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g(i) < \infty$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k_1 \geq k_2 \geq N$, $\sum_{i=k_1}^{k_2} g(i) < \epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon$. Then
$$\| s_{k_1} - s_{k_2}\| = \|\sum_{i=k_1}^{k_2} f_n(i)\| \leq \sum_{i=k_1}^{k_2} \|f_n(i)\| \leq \sum_{i=k_1}^{k_2} g(i) < \epsilon,$$
so $s_k$ is Cauchy and thus converges, so the series $\sum_{i\geq 1} f_n(i)$ converges.

 I also need to show that the series $\sum_{i\geq 1} f(i)$ converges and that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i\geq 1} f_n(i) = \sum_{i\geq 1} f(i).$$
I am not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward, just using the same remark you have for $g$
More precisely, for any $N>0$ we have:
$$ \| \sum_{i \ge 1} f_n(i)-f(i) \| \le  \| \sum_{i \ge 1}^N f_n(i)-f(i) \|  + \| \sum_{i \ge N+1} f_n(i)-f(i) \| \le \underbrace{\| \sum_{i \ge 1}^N f_n(i)-f(i) \|}_{ \longrightarrow 0 \text{ when } n \rightarrow +\infty}+2 \sum_{i \ge N+1} \| g(i) \|  $$

Thus,
$$ \limsup_n  \| \sum_{i \ge 1} f_n(i)-f(i) \| \le 2 \sum_{i \ge N+1} \| g(i) \|  \quad \forall N$$
Hence the conclusion.

Comment: I don't really understand where the first inequality with $2 \sum \|g(i)\|$ comes from.

Comment: Ah, as $\lim f_n(i) = f(i)$, you have $ \| f(i)\| \le \|g(i) \|$ ( and of course, $\| f_n(i)\| \le \|g(i)\|$